# Integration of irrational Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Integrate the irrational Functions $$f(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\{(\xi-1)(\xi+1)(\xi-i)\}^{-\frac{2}{3}}d\xi=?$$
PS:This question comes from Schwarz–Christoffel mapping, $A+C\int^z\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\xi-z_k)^{\alpha_k-1}d\xi $ take a unit circle onto a polygon. so $A+Cf(z)$ is a conformal map from unit circle to a regular triangle.($-1,1,i$ respectively corresponding the vertexs of triangle)